# Google cloud platform custom prediction routine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I’m trying to deploy my custom predictor in Google cloud AI platform. I have created a version of the model successfully with `--enable-logging` flag, and previously I have tested the code in local and it’s working properly.

However, when I try to request an online prediction, this returns the following error:

```
{u'error': u'Prediction failed: unknown error.'}
```

The Stackdriver logging does not appear any log.

**How can i find logs on gcp cloud when i run following prediction command**

```
gcloud ai-platform predict --model gpt_simple --version v1 --json-instances $INPUT_DATA_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

How can i find logs on gcp cloud when i run following prediction command

In order to access the logs generated from either creating a model or a version, navigate to the following from within your project console;

From the Sidebar menu navigate to, 
StackDriver --> Logging --> Logs Viewer

You then need to select the following, 
Audited Resources --> ml.googleapis.com --->

You will then see the two options below,

google.cloud.ml.v1.ModelService.CreateModel

google.cloud.ml.v1.ModelService.CreateVersion